# How to expose internal control's property to its parent UserControl in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, properties, user-controls

I have a DialogPrompt UserControl that will have an Image and a TextBlock. Here is the template:

```
    <UserControl>   
      <Button x:Name="_OkButton" Content="OK"/>
      <DockPanel >
        <Image/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="_DialogTextBox" />
      </DockPanel>
    </UserControl>
```

How do I expose Source property of the Image and Text property of the TextBlock inside my UserControl?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would create two `DependencyProperties`, one for the `Text` and one for the `Image` `Source`.

The `Image` `Source` `DependencyProperty` will automatically set the inner `Image` control's source whenever it is updated. Similarly, the `Text` `DependencyProperty` will be setting the `Text` of the inner `TextBlock` control as well.

Here is the setup:

```cs
    public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
    {
        #region ImageSource
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.Register
            ( 
                "ImageSource", 
                typeof(Uri),
                typeof(MyUserControl), 
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnImageSourceChanged))
            );
     
        public Uri ImageSource
        {
            get { return (Uri)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
        }
        #endregion ImageSource
    
        #region Text
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.Register
            ( 
                "Text", 
                typeof(string),
                typeof(MyUserControl), 
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("")
            );
     
        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }
        #endregion Text
    
        public MyUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    
        private static void OnImageSourceChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var myUserControl = sender as MyUserControl;
            if (myUserControl != null)
            {
                myUserControl.ImageSource.Source = new BitmapImage((Uri) e.NewValue);
            }
        }
    }
```

Whenever the `Image` `Source` changes, this will automatically update the source of the inner `Image` control. Note, we need to do some conversion here since the `Image` control itself uses an `ImageSource` type.

XAML can then be updated to:

```xml
       <UserControl x:Name="ControlName">   
          <Button x:Name = "OkButton" Content="OK"/>
          <DockPanel >
            <Image x:Name = "MyImage" />
            <TextBlock x:Name = "DialogTextBox" Text="{Binding ElementName=ControlName, Path=Text}"/>
          </DockPanel>
        </UserControl>
```

Here, the inner `TextBlock` control simply binds to the `Text` `DependencyProperty` of the parent (the main `UserControl`).

Answer (score 7):

In your code behind, add 2 DependencyProperties and bind them to your Image Source and to your TextBlock Text.

Here is a tutorial on how to use and create Dependency Properties :
http://www.wpftutorial.net/dependencyproperties.html

For your binding in your xaml, here is an example :

```
<Image Source="{Binding YourProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=YourUserControl}}/>
```

Comment: +1 for the first correct answer, however @d.moncada's answer is much better because it contains a more detailed explanation (as opposed to just a link)